# Javascript jQuery does not change value on true condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#leftmenu>li').on('click', function() {
    var sessionActive = "false";
    $.get("Session/Index/", function(data, status) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            sessionActive = "true";
            alert(data.length);
        }
    });
    alert(sessionActive);
});
```

In the above javascript function, I don't understand why the value for sessionActive does not change to "true" when the length of data is greater than 0. In the `alert(data.length);` I see a positive number due to my test page (Session/Index) having data, but the second alert displays false, as if the assignment to true never happened. How can I get this to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Please also indent proper. It was not clear that the $.get was inside the click

Comment: @squint: I see no reason to replace the one I used with a different one. Indeed, I see basically no reason for that more-recent question vs. the earlier one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - actually he did not return sessionActive, only modified it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: He's not returning anything.

Comment: @squint: It really doesn't matter, the question still gets answered there.

Comment: @mplungjan: I reopened it and then closed it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Eliminates a potential point of confusion for someone already confused by the problem.

Comment: @squint: Meh. :-) But no biggie. I'm just not a fan of manufactured "canonical" questions posted after real ones that could be turned into canonical ones instead. But hey, I fairly routinely don't get my way. :-)